# runc and ctr commands do not show docker images and containers

Tags: docker, runc, containerd

I have multiple Docker images and containers running on a VM. But commands like "runc list" doesn't list any of these.

How can I make runc/containerd aware of my existing docker images?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The runtime (`runc`) uses so-called *runtime root directory* to store and obtain the information about containers. Under this root directory, `runc` places sub-directories (one per container), and each of them contains the `state.json` file, where the container state description resides.

The default location for runtime root directory is either `/run/runc` (for non-rootless containers) or `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/runc` (for rootless containers) - the latter also usually points to somewhere under `/run` (e.g. `/run/user/$UID/runc`).

When the container engine invokes `runc`, it may override the default runtime root directory and specify the custom one (`--root` option of `runc`). Docker uses this possibility, e.g. on my box, it specifies `/run/docker/runtime-runc/moby` as the runtime root.

That said, to make `runc list` see your Docker containers, you have to point it to Docker's runtime root directory by specifying `--root` option. Also, given that Docker containers are not rootless by default, you will need the appropriate privileges to access the runtime root (e.g. with `sudo`).

So, that's how this should work:

```
$ docker run -d alpine sleep 1000
4acd4af5ba8da324b7a902618aeb3fd0b8fce39db5285546e1f80169f157fc69

$ sudo runc --root /run/docker/runtime-runc/moby/ list
ID                                                                 PID         STATUS      BUNDLE                                                                                                                               CREATED                          OWNER
4acd4af5ba8da324b7a902618aeb3fd0b8fce39db5285546e1f80169f157fc69   18372       running     /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/4acd4af5ba8da324b7a902618aeb3fd0b8fce39db5285546e1f80169f157fc69   2019-07-12T17:33:23.401746168Z   root
```

As to *images*, you can not make `runc` see them, as it has no notion of image at all - instead, it operates on [bundles](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/master/bundle.md). Creating the bundle (e.g. based on image) is responsibility of the caller (in your case - containerd).

Comment: How do you find the runtime root directory?

Comment: @SamThomas I'm not sure that there is a simple way to make Docker tell you about this, as this is kinda "implementation detail". Speaking about non-trivial ways of doing this - probably `strace`ing `containerd` (as @Niklas proposed to you in [your thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738905/how-to-list-docker-containers-using-runc)) is the most universal approach, as it will reveal the actual parameters which are passed to `runc`. Sorry, but I can't propose anything better (actually, I used the same way to determine the runtime directory location on my machine when I wrote this post).

Comment: yeah :( . I wish runc atleast maintained a list of all roots that were used to start containers with