# How to list docker containers using runc

Tags: docker, runc

From what I can tell `runc list` allows to pass a root directory for container storage. But I can't figure out what root directory to pass for docker. I tried `/var/lib/docker/containers` but it says container don't exist. I do have containers showing up in `docker ps` (fyi).

Or am I wrong in assuming that docker still uses runc to run containers?

EDIT: Based on Niklas's answer. Is there a way of finding root directories for runc - from docker or the scanning the file system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Root directory is in different place.
You could use

```
sudo runc --root /run/docker/runtime-runc/moby  list
```

One way for finding root directory is looking for init arguments:

```
 ps aux | grep runtime-root
```

Which should show argument for `-runtime-root`, and inside there are usually at least `moby` named directory, in case of Docker.

Second way is for looking Docker containerd  configuration

```
/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
```

Where is default `runtime_root`

Third way, in case you have `/etc/docker/daemon.json` existing, there is place for `runtime` configuration.

Fourth way (Be careful with this one!). Get PID of `containerd`

Inspect process with strace and look for execve calls:
`sudo strace -f -e execve -p <PID>`

Restart/start some  container. And you might see some calls e.g:

```
execve("/usr/sbin/runc", ["runc", "--root", "/var/run/docker/runtime-runc/mob"
```

More info: [runc and ctr commands do not show docker images and containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009928/runc-and-ctr-commands-do-not-show-docker-images-and-containers)

Comment: Yes I saw this, but the post does not talk about finding this root directory.

Comment: I added one way to find it.

Comment: root       1450  0.0  0.5 1307236 68028 ?       Ssl  Apr30  11:14 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Comment: Thats what I got, no --runtime-root in there

Comment: I noticed problem in there, it expected that docker was in path name, new update

Comment: I have nothing like that on my system :'(

Comment: Seems like `runtime-root` parameter is specific for `containerd-shim`, and you don't have it running I guess?

Comment: I just have docker installed

Comment: I added two methods more, but there ends my knowledge.